# How can I stop repeating code for accessing value of associated type enum?

Tags: swift

I want to access to value of my enum in case, I made a switch for getting access to value, but as you can see I am reaping my codes, how can i do this in better way?

```
enum TestEnum {
    case a(value: Int)
    case b(value: Int)
    case c(value: Int)
    
    var value: Int {
        switch self {
        case .a(let value):
            return value
        case .b(let value):
            return value
        case .c(let value):
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could change the way your data is modeled

```
struct MyStruct {
  enum Kind {
    case one, two, three
  }
  
  let kind: Kind
  let value: Int
}
```

Comment: was just going to suggest the same thing

Comment: The question is about accessing value of Enum not the use case of a struct.

Comment: But I have to say you find a good shortcut.

Comment: If all cases are always required to have the same type of variable, then IMO this is the best solution.  Maybe even more correct approach to use the data structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var value: Int {
    switch self {
    case .a(let value),
         .b(let value),
         .c(let value):
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: emmm, I wanted get rid of switch completely.

Comment: @macCoder2022 maybe you should specify this in the question. How is anyone meant to know you want to remove the switch rather than reforming the switch?

Comment: emmm, I thought that would be clear that switch is the issue of repeating codes, it works, but because of nature of itself, we have to mention all cases, so I thought it should be a way that does not need to use switch in enum.

Comment: @macCoder2022: There's no way to get rid of the `switch`, you can only make it shorter like Samps demonstrated. Well, technically you can also use `if case .a(let value) = self` and so on. Having multiple enum values _all_ (without exception) with the same associated value type is so rare, it's not worth adding a shorthand to the Swift language.